# search a list of parameter in JSON list/object Python

Tags: python, json

I am using below data set which uses SQL to query the data.
The results are in JSON list and not object.
I try to do slicing but couldn't make it work on the list. So used SQL queries(Query 1) to filter the columns instead.
Now I am trying to take a list of parameters and search it in the query results so my results are filtered to only items in the list.
Example my_list['60', '61', '62', '63', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72]
I want the result to shows the 5 columns including only the above precincts.
Any hep appreciated, because I been stuck for days.

```
data_url='data.cityofnewyork.us'  
data_set='nc67-uf89'      
url = Socrata(data_url) 
JSON_results = url.get(data_set, limit=100)
print(JSON_results)

Query1 = url.get(data_set, select="precinct, violation, fine_amount, interest_amount, issuing_agency" where= interest_amount>0",order="interest_amount DESC",  limit=10)
print(Query1)
#  this is the result of Query 1 {'precinct': '013', 'violation': 'COMML PLATES-UNALTERED VEHICLE', 'fine_amount': '495', 'interest_amount': '349.72', 'issuing_agency': 'TRAFFIC'}

if Query1['precinct']==mylist:
for i in Query1:
    print (i)

#Below is output for JSON_results

[{'plate': 'GDP4579', 'state': 'NY', 'license_type': 'PAS', 'summons_number': '5104469750', 'issue_date': '11/17/2018', 'violation_time': '11:37A', 'violation': 'FAILURE TO STOP AT RED LIGHT', 'fine_amount': '50', 'penalty_amount': '25', 'interest_amount': '0', 'reduction_amount': '0', 'payment_amount': '75', 'amount_due': '0', 'precinct': '000', 'county': 'BK', 'issuing_agency': 'DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION', 'summons_image': {'url': 'http://nycserv.nyc.gov/NYCServWeb/ShowImage?searchID=VGxSRmQwNUVVVEpQVkdNeFRVRTlQUT09&locationName=_____________________', 'description': 'View Summons'}}]
```

Comment: Can you post the results of `print(JSON_results)`?

Comment: I just edited it with the results,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make some assumptions about the data structure of `JSON_Results` but hopefully this can get you in the right direction.

```
# This is the structure I am assuming for json results
import json 
JSON_RESULTS = json.loads(
    '[{"precinct":"001","fine":32},{"precinct":"002","fine":44},{"precinct":"003","fine":12}]')
print(JSON_RESULTS)
```

returns

```
[{'precinct': '001', 'fine': 32}, {'precinct': '002', 'fine': 44}, {'precinct': '003', 'fine': 12}]
```

if thats the case, then you should be able to filter these results in your for loop

```
my_list = ['60', '61', '62', '63', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72']
for jsonResult in JSON_RESULTS:
    if jsonResult['precinct'] in  my_list:
        print(f"{jsonResult['precinct']},{jsonResult['violation']},{jsonResult['fine_amount']},{jsonResult['interest_amount']},{jsonResult['issuing_agency']}")
```

*edit: just print the columns you want

Comment: Wow...Thank you, It worked. I was way off plus I had to convert my list to strings. I been stuck for days on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#### make sure my_list is str '013' not a int 013 cause  '013' not equal to 013.
Query_1 = {'precinct': '013', 'violation': 'COMML PLATES-UNALTERED VEHICLE', 'fine_amount': '495', 'interest_amount': '349.72', 'issuing_agency': 'TRAFFIC'}

my_list = ['013','60', '61', '62', '63', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72']

if Query_1['precinct'] in my_list:
           print(Query_1)
```

Comment: I tried that but get an error, the issue is Query 1 is a list of dictionories [{....},{...}]. below is the error i get.                   
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str